# Persisting data in docker's volume for Oracle database

Tags: docker, oracle11g, persistence, volume

I created volume for storing my application database data - `docker volume create dbvolume`.

Then I launched my docker container with Oracle XE 11g database image and data volume.

`docker run --name=OracleXE --shm-size=1g -p 1521:1521 -p 8080:8080 -e ORACLE_PWD=weblogic1 -v dbvolume:/opt/oracle/oradata oracle/database:11.2.0.2-xe`

Stored some entries in database. Stopped and removed container then launched it again, but no data persisted in database.

How can I get persisted data on subsequent requests to application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase

```
-v /opt/oracle/oradata
              The data volume to use for the database.
              Has to be writable by the Unix "oracle" (uid: 54321) user inside the container!
              If omitted the database will not be persisted over container recreation.
```

Comment: Yes, this seems correct, just one refinement about Oracle's database versions: for 11g - ```-v /u01/app/oracle/oradata``` but for 12c - ```-v /opt/oracle/oradata```

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is not correct for Oracle 11g XE, that is asked in this question.
"/u01/app/oracle" should be mapped with a volume (e.g. -v dbvolume:/u01/app/oracle)